# boost C++ library in R language (Windows)

Tags: c++, r, boost

I installed package BH in order to have access to boost C++ library. The installation was successful, however when I use the following lines in C++ file:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include "boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp"
```

I am getting an error that the file "boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp" cannot be found.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It would be far easier to install boost libraries actually built for being used from C++: try `apt-get install libboost-all-dev` (depending on what os you are on)

Comment: Oh wait I just noticed you are on windows. I recommend the `vcpkg` tool by Microsoft for installing boost as it will automatically link it.

Comment: I installed boost using vcpkg tool. In Visual Studio, the boost library is available, but not from R. I also tried to reinstall BH R package but was still unsuccessful. I am getting the same error that the file cannot be found.

Comment: Have you added `LinkingTo: Rcpp, BH` in your `DESCRIPTION` file?

Comment: yes, I have forgotten to add LinkingTo: Rcpp, BH in DESCRIPTION file. Now, all is working smoothly. Thank you for your help